# How to add ListView Elements programatically in same windows as the textfield ist?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I´m new in Android Development and want to build a little application.

This is how the Layout looks like.

This is my layout code (cant´t post picture because I´m a new user):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/help_add"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editVoc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_add" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my java code now.

```
public class AddItemsToList extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

VocabularySet vocabularySet = new VocabularySet();
private TextView t;
private Button btn_add;
private Button btn_done;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.add_items_to_list);
    vocabularySet.listName = NewList.listName;

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listName);
    t.setText(vocabularySet.listName);

    btn_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);
    btn_done.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.add: 
        EditText word = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editVoc);
        vocabularySet.addListElement(word.getText().toString());

        /* setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView1, vocabularySet.words));

         ListView lv = getListView();

         lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);*/

        //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.listView1, vocabularySet.words);




      break;
     case R.id.done:
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(string.error_listname_missing).setNeutralButton(string.error_ok, null).show();
      break;
     }

}
```

}

I tried a few things like setting List Adapter etc. but nothing worked for me, how can i add Words in this empty List (ListView)?

Comment: Okay, i found a perfect example for this in the Android Sample Project "ApiDemos" (List12.java)